# Export netbean javadb project with database

Tags: java

I have created java database project in the netbean ide. It works fine and I created jar file for it. It's also execute successfully. I wanna run it on another computer. I copy entire application folder to a other computer. When it excutes I can see the GUI window correctly and all function correctly work except the database. I can't get information from database. It's ok because I can't see a database in copied files. I know that db exist on only my netbean installed computer. So how can I send this database file to another computer? Everything I want is to copy my application to pen driver and run it on any computer which has installed java but not netbean. Any help?

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Sorry I do not have experience in `derby` database. You can take a look http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminparttwo.html

Comment: i used netbean java derby database which comes with netbean 
my database url is 
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/School [admin1 on ADMIN1] //display name
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/School //database url
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver //database driver
this image : u can guess what is my database i actually don't know what is my database but i know it's not ms access or mysql.
 http://i43.tinypic.com/f2ipw1.jpg

Comment: Your database seems to be `School`

Comment: i know it..that's not what i need